# Why do I get an error that says "Server Execution Failed" everytime I try to open things?

Tags: windows-explorer

I get the error "Server Execution Failed" when trying to open different things. I can open some things, but I get the error whenever I try to open Control Panel, Documents, Program Files, C:\Windows, etc., and files such as regedit.exe, cmd.exe, and so on. I tried to fix it by typing a command in cmd, but as I said, cmd doesn't even open. Neither does regedit; I would change a registry key because I read somewhere that it'd work, but regedit says "disabled by administrator".

Comment: Can we get some more information about the issue? What version of windows are you running? Is this a fresh install, or have you been running it for a while? Have you made any hardware changes recently? What software changes have you made?

Comment: What error does regedit give? "Disabled by Administrator" or "Server Execution Failed"? What about cmd?

Comment: is this your own machine? e.g. are you the administrator? or is it the pc at work?